# Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof..., Property 'extend' does not exist on type 'typeof

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am building my vue app for the first time with TypeScript and I have been stuck on this `Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'typeof` issue. I have researched similar problems but none seemed to work. I am on `"vue": "^3.0.0-0"` and `"typescript": "~3.9.3"`

I installed vuetify, so in my vuetify.ts I have the first error(Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
})
```

I am passing it in my main.ts

```
createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app')
```

Then on my App.vue where lies the other error (Property 'extend' does not exist on type 'typeof) I have

```
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    //
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  })
})
```

I have also followed the configurations recommended [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html)

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the body of the question.

Comment: @JaredSmith done. Hopefully, that helps

Comment: "Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof" typeof what? I'd bet that the error message does not contain an unclosed quote. Please include the **exact** error message.

Comment: No point in grilling OP for error messages. They have provided version information which clearly points at API change in v3. See answer by jeremy castelli

Comment: I know this is older post but I am also stuck on same place. Can you let me know how you solved problem. I am getting same for Vuex while creating store in Vue3

Comment: You can have a look at this repo @Rutu https://github.com/Simpcyclassy/tandem_quiz

Comment: Thanks @Ada i switched back to Vue 2 for now as vue3 is not stable yet

Answer (score 20):

`Vue 3` has just been released.
and there is no `Vue.use()` method anymore.
the correct way now is as you did

```
createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .use(vuetify) // there
  .mount('#app')
```

same for `Vue.extend()` it doesn't exist anymore.

I don't know if vuetify is ready for vue 3 now, maybe the doc is not updated yet.

You should either downgrade Vue to version 2.X or start learning vue 3 and wait a bit that all the documentations are ready