# Why "use" property does not exist in type "typeof import?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I try to use Vuex and i have this in index.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

But i have this error:

> Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof import("D:/\u041F\u0440\u043E\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043C\u043C\u0438\u0440\u043E\u0432\u0430\u043D\u0438\u0435/Vue/asd/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")'.

Comment: Are you using Vue 3.x or Vue 2,x? Vue.use is not longer exist in Vue 3.x https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api.html#a-new-global-api-createapp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof..., Property 'extend' does not exist on type 'typeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032296/property-use-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-property-extend-does-not-exi)